# Flutter TextField focus rebuilds widget if keyboardType changes

Tags: forms, flutter, textfield, bloc

Trying to build my first app on Flutter, but ran into a problem. Searched a lot, but everyone is having a bit different problems (keyboard closes, stream calls, etc.)

I try to use BLoC pattern and rxDart to listen and validate fields. Everything works well if all `TextField`s have same `keyboardType`, but I have different inputs (number, link, ...) and every time I tap on an input, keyboard is changed and that triggers Widget to rebuild.

Any way to keep my Streams intact of rebuilding a widget on keyboard change?

Edit: Actually the same happens if I use `ShowDialog()` on that page and close it with `Navigator.of(context).pop();`. I understand it's a page change and widget gets rebuilt, but how can I keep data in BLoC's streams of that widget?

Or how do I add to sinks my inputs' values after widget is rebuilt?

Comment: You should build your code so that rebuilds don't cause issues. `build()` can be called multiple times at various times.

Comment: Yes, now I'm aware of that. The only solution I think of, is wrapping whole `MaterialApp` with BLoC, but would love to keep it Widget specific. It seems like it looses the purpose if it's wrapping whole app.